# Git manipulation from within a Groovy system script in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I'm using the Groovy plugin in Jenkins, and would like to manipulate some Git repositories.

I would like to:

- in repo `A`, checkout commit `X`
- in repo `B`, checkout commit `Y`
- in repo `C`, make a commit and push

I'm happy if someone can point me out how to do this using the Git plugin (within Groovy), or how to call system commands in a particular path (something like `"git checkout X".execute(in_this_path)` would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is to change the working directory, so can you work on multiple git repositories in different paths. To solve it I use java.lang.ProcessBuilder which has directory(File directory) method, that changes the working directory.
here is a full example:

```
//executes the command in the  working dir 
//and prints the output to a log file
def runProcess(workingDir, command) {
    ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    procBuilder.directory(workingDir);
    procBuilder.redirectOutput(new File("${workingDir}/groovyGit.log"))

    Process proc = procBuilder.start();

    def exitVal = proc.waitFor()
    println "Exit value: ${exitVal}"

    return proc
}

//configuring the working dir for each git repository
def repoA = "repo A working dir"
def repoB = "repo B working dir"
def repoC = "repo C working dir"

//configuring the wanted revision to checkout for each repository
def repoARevision = "repo a revision"
def repoBRevision = "repo b revision"

def commitMsg = "commit msg"

//checkout A
runProcess(new File(repoA), ["git", "checkout", repoARevision])

//checkout B
runProcess(new File(repoB), ["git", "checkout", repoBRevision])

//check status before commit
runProcess(new File(repoC), ["git", "status"])

//commit
runProcess(new File(repoC), ["git", "commit", "-a", "-m", commitMsg])
```